# Angular enable/disable contenteditable on div element

Tags: javascript, angular

### Problem

I want to bind a boolean to the `contenteditable` directive to a div which does not work.

**Output:**

> Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

### Tries

1. I tried to add `[]` brackets to bind a variable to it. `editable` is a component property type boolean

```
<div class="text-editor"
     [contenteditable]="editable"></div>
```

2. I also tried to add double curly brackets `{{}}` which leads to the same issue

```
<div class="text-editor"
     contenteditable="{{editable}}"></div>
```

### It works in this cases

If I simply set the string `true` without any brackets then it works, **but this solution does not solve my requirement since I want to change the behaviour dynamically**

```
<div class="text-editor"
     contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I couldn't find any solution on questions at SO. I hope you know a solution and can share it with me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use either `[attr.contenteditable]="editable"`

or `[contentEditable]="editable"`

The "attr." prefix will emit an attribute for whatever suffix you use.

```
<div [attr.contenteditable]="editable">Edit me!</div>
```

OR

```
<div [contentEditable]="editable">Edit me!</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xablzf

Comment: demo links are great but It always good to include the code here in answer as well.

Comment: This is genius, works like a charm. Big thank you! (will accept in some minutes when its available)